# Pointer Detective - Inspecting an Object (instance) and Doing a "PointerDetective openOn: self." leads to a System Error in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Pointer Detective - Inspecting an Object (instance) and Doing a "PointerDetective openOn: self." leads to a System Error in Pharo?

The object is a WhateverRoot instance (subclass of WAComponent) that has "canBeRoot ^true."

Am I doing something wrong?

**PS.** My "eagle eye" caught a typo on line 9 of the error. "'*Orginal* error:' ,title asString.". Maybe, just maybe...

[image: System Error screen capture]

Comment: Hi, I think it makes more sense to write an email to Pharo mailing list, as this is not really a common issue. You can find the addresses here: http://pharo.org/community

Comment: Forwarding to pharo-dev list.

Comment: Super. I posted it on pharo-users.

Comment: @unmircea Remember to answer you own question here once you get the problem solved (e.g., with the help of the Pharo community.) Having more Smalltalk presence here in SO is a good thing.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia I will. Bookmarked.

Comment: Added what I managed to dig around the problem... see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pharo 3:** 
Managed to zero in closer to the issue. It seems the problem only happens with the latest commit (10) of PointerDetective. The one before that (9) works as advertised. This "weak self" error only happens on the latest commit.

**Squeak 4.5 and Pharo 4 (bleeding edge):** Also tried the latest commit (10) on Squeak 4.5 All In One and on the latest Build of Pharo 4 and they both pop up a Debugger instead of the White Crash.

Easy to replicate, even the example on the [smalltalkhub](http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~BenComan/PointerDetective) page crashes it.

Steps to replicate:

1. Get Pharo 3
2. Open Monticello
3. Add repository.
4. Open repository.
5. Choose latest commit (10)
6. Load
7. Open Workspace

Paste in **example** and Do It -> White screen press esc to remove.

```
testObject := 'END5'.
ref1 := { testObject. nil }.
ref2 := { ref1 }.
ref3 := PDTestResource new heldObject: ref2. 
ref1 at: 2 put: ref3.  "note the reference loop this creates"
PointerDetective openOn: testObject.
```